# Angular Console Errors Not Failing Unit Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

So I'm not sure if this is something that has changed over the Angular versions however when I ran `ng test` previously the tests used to fail if you had not imported certain components into the tests which you would need to do to pass the tests.

However now I notice that the tests still pass however the console is full of errors about elements not being known because they are components I have not imported into the tests. Eg:

[image: Console Errors]

As you can see tests still pass:
[image: Test Results]

So I'm not sure if there is a specific setting or flag you should set to fail tests on these kinds of errors? Please let me know if I can provide more info.

I'm not really sure what to try.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36430 I think you're facing that. Unfortunately, I don't know of a solution.

Comment: Had to use the workaround described in that post, thanks @AliF50